# How to name a newly added NIC in Linux

Tags: linux, network-adapter

I'd like to name a newly added NIC as `eth4`. How can I do that under Linux？

To be specific, the distribution I use is SUSE, SP1. I guess there is a one to one mapping between the NIC hardware and the `ethx` like name?

Comment: Did you manage to rename the NIC using the solution I propose below?

Answer (score 0):

(This applies to SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 and 11.)

The file you're looking for is `/etc/udev/rules.d/30-net_persistent_names.rules`.

Its contents look like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", SYSFS{address}=="0b:a0:c0:ff:ee:bb", IMPORT="/lib/udev/rename_netiface %k ethX"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", SYSFS{address}=="de:ad:be:ff:0b:bb", IMPORT="/lib/udev/rename_netiface %k ethY"
```

Locate the line that applies to your new ethernet interface (it is the line in which the `SYSFS{address}` entry coincides with the MAC address of the new NIC), replace `ethX` with `eth4` and save the file.

Now we must take care of any existing configuration files.

Change directory to `/etc/sysconfig/network/` and look for a file called `ifcfg-eth-<MAC address of new network interface>`. Open it and, if present, replace:

```
DEVICE=ethX
```

with

```
DEVICE=eth4
```

If you can't find a file named `ifcfg-eth-<MAC address of new network interface>` but you see files with pattern `ifcfg-ethXX` look for the file that contains the MAC adress of the new NIC:

```
grep "<MAC adress of new NIC>" ifcfg-eth*
```

(MAC adress should be in format `00:11:22:33:44:55`.)

replace as explained above the `DEVICE` entry (if present) and **rename** the file to `ifcfg-eth4`.

If you didn't find any file either named `ifcfg-eth-<MAC address of new network interface>` or `ifcfg-ethXX` that's OK, this simply means it wasn't configured automatically.

Reboot the computer. You should see now an interface called `eth4`.